# Getting Product or ProductID in magento

Tags: magento

when writing a new set of .phtml & block:
What is the recommanded way to know if the block is currently on a product page ?
If it is on a product page then how do I get to the data of the currently being viewed product ?

Thanks,
Eyal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1st question) How to know that you're on product view page.

Your problem is not clear because you don't say the purpose of such functionality. I interpret your question as "How can my blockknow that it's embedded in Product View page and not in some other page?".

The most common way is to get layout of page and search it for standard block designed to view product. So in your block you can make following request:

```
$block = $this->getLayout()
    ->getBlock('product.info');

if ($block) {
    // Block exists - you're viewing product page
}
```

The other method is to check layout handles used to form current page layout:

```
$handles = $this->->getLayout()
    ->getUpdate()
    ->getHandles();
if (in_array('catalog_product_view', $handles)) {
    // Handle exists - you're viewing product page
}
```

However it's more concrete method, it returns positive result only when viewing product page and not pages with similar designs using product view blocks. For, example Product Review page will show you same product page with minor differences but it uses its own (not 'catalog_product_view') handle for it. As far as you said nothing about your purpose I cannot recommend you to choose first or second method.

Notice: you architecture can be wrong, because usually
a) your block either doesn't need to know where it's embedded, so it doesn't need not check currently viewed page
b) or your block is used only for product view page. But in this case it's a layout xml task to put your block only in required pages and blocks.

2nd question) How to get current product on product view page.

Use following code:

```
  $product = Mage::registry('current_product');
```

And you'll get the product currently viewed.

Comment: being new magento I am not sure I tottaly understand the handles concept but the first option sounds like what I was aiming at. 
I want this information so that a block I am writing that Is supposed to be inserted via the layout on a page that has a product view on it will be able to gracefully fail if inserted on another location. 
can You tell me what is the difference between `$product = Mage::registry('current_product');` and `$product = Mage::registry('product');`  ?

Comment: Registry keeps variables. In first case you ask it for 'current_product' variable, in second - for 'product' variable. What's kept in these variables - only scripts that work together know. On product view page both these variables are filled with same product instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can check current request object - it holds all data about module, controller, action and params which is currently in use. After that you could compare it with product page ones: does the module, controller and action the same and does product id matches

But you should aware of third-party customizations which could replace standard Magento product view controller with theirs ones

Comment: I mean you should get product view module and controller from config, not just use default one

Comment: o.k. can you provide more details? 
I thought that I will have to somehow lookup a product view block within the layout. because anyone can add a new action that eventually will have a product view within it, can't they ?
also what about the second part of my Q?

Comment: So, first of all you should decide what page is considered to be product view page. Default for product #1 is catalog/product/view/id/1. You could put Mage::app()->getRequest() - and check module and controller. The second part of your question - you can get the id of product just prom request, parameter id. Look at Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View::getProduct()

Answer (score 0):

This will let you know what product is being viewed.

```
Mage::registry('current_product')
```

If there is a `current_product` then you are *probably* on a product page, although this doesn't guarantee the page is being handled by a catalog controller.

Comment: can You tell me what is the difference between `$product = Mage::registry('current_product');` and `$product = Mage::registry('product');`  ?

Comment: On product pages, none. Both are set at the same time. `product` is set in a couple of other places such as the product's 'email to a friend' page.