# programmatically determine what product I am viewing in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have some special functions that need to run per specific products in magento. Is there a way to get the product ID via PHP in the single product page template?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Product or ProductID in magento](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4646012/471559) or [Magento pass current product ID to module](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8174021/471559)

Comment: not exactly sure what you are asking... you could always put in conditional things like `if(something) { //do this }` in php, you would just need to look at the script/page responsible for product output.

Answer (score 0):

```
<path_to_your_template_folder>/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
$_sku     = $this->getItem()->getSku();
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $_sku);
$_product->getEntityId(); // here is your ID
```

Taken [shamelessly] from this blog post: http://till.klampaeckel.de/blog/archives/126-Magento-Loading-the-product-from-a-template.html

Also, I saw this suggestion:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku);
```